# How to use off line/cache database and synchronise with online server

Tags: database, postgresql, offline, libreoffice, synchronize

I want to use offline and locale data base and when network is available, send data to the server. What are solutions ?

Server is linux running postgresql 9.5 or higher. Local and offline data base is Libreoffice 6.2.7 or OpenOffice for WINDOWS7 and WIndows10 64bits

I think about sql code to do the task but I never found how to deal with two database in an sql code.
It is like INSERT ... TO ... database.table ...

Comment: Could you re-phrase the question? I think it needs some more detail or context.  And what is a `locale data base`?  Do you mean `local database`?  So you want to use and "offline" and "local" database together?  And then when the network is available, you also want to "send data to the server" (a 3rd database)?  And you are using Libreoffice to connect to Postgres (I've never heard of such a thing)?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Local database = offline database. Both are the same thing. I want to use Libre Office Base for it. The second database is Postgresql. Most of the time I do not have network or internet connection and forced to record data on Libre Office.Then, when network is available I want to send the data from libre office to the remote server Postgresql. How to do this process ? What are solutions ?